# How do I sort a ruby array created from multiple mongo queries pushed into the array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, mongodb, sorting

I have some code like this:

```
@acct_cust.each do |ac|
      @jobAc << Job.where(:customer_id => ac.id).sort(:start_date)
    end
```

And I want to sort ALL the results by my start_date parameter.  Because this loops through each customer and gets their jobs, it's sorting the jobs for the customer (ac) in blocks, shoving that into the array, and then in my view we're printing out all the customers and their jobs, ordered by customer and then by job start_date.

What I want is to execute the block above, and then AFTER that, do a sort! or sort_by on that block.  But however I try to write the statement, I get "undefined method sort_by for <#Array..." type stuff.

What am I missing?

I could also alternatively use associations in my models to link the account THROUGH the customer TO the job, but I haven't figured that out either.  Right now job belongs_to customer, and customer belongs_to account - so how do I write my query directly like:

```
@jobAc = Job.where(:customer_id => account.customer.id).sort(:start_date)
```

(that definitely won't work I'm aware - but something to that effect?)

Comment: Are you trying to sort Ruby array, or you want mongodb return sorted result?